# How do I send a HEAD request for a static sendFile in fastify?

Tags: fastify

When I try to send a `HEAD` request for `sendFile` I get the following error:

```js
app.head(filePath, { logLevel: LOG_LEVEL }, async (request, reply) => {
    console.log('head');
    try {
      const { '*': uriPath } = request.params;
      const isFile = !!uriPath.match(/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}(\?.*)?/);
      if (isFile) {
        setCacheControl(reply, FILE_CACHE_CONTROL_MAX_AGE);
        reply.sendFile(uriPath);
      } else {
        const indexPath = 'index.html';
        const indexStr = await fs.readFile(path.join(serveRoot, indexPath), {
          encoding: 'utf-8',
        });
        const indexPayload = await injectEnv(indexStr);
        setCacheControl(reply, INDEX_CACHE_CONTROL_MAX_AGE);
        reply.type('text/html');
        reply.send(indexPayload);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  });
```

```
web_1  | {"level":50,"time":1580244056047,"pid":1,"hostname":"3ee631923a16","reqId":5,"err":{"type":"FastifyError","message":"FST_ERR_PROMISE_NOT_FULLFILLED: Promise may not be fulfilled with 'undefined' when statusCode is not 204","stack":"FastifyError [FST_ERR_PROMISE_NOT_FULLFILLED]: FST_ERR_PROMISE_NOT_FULLFILLED: Promise may not be fulfilled with 'undefined' when statusCode is not 204\n    at /usr/src/server/node_modules/fastify/lib/wrapThenable.js:34:30\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)","name":"FastifyError [FST_ERR_PROMISE_NOT_FULLFILLED]","code":"FST_ERR_PROMISE_NOT_FULLFILLED","statusCode":500},"msg":"Promise may not be fulfilled with 'undefined' when statusCode is not 204","v":1}
```

The way that express handles this is by simply passing through `HEAD` requests to the `GET` method, and then letting `send` (the underlying package that sends responses for both fastify and express) handle it [here](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/blob/ea1748a3b3e00dbcbb0629cf368ced575c6ab7d6/index.js#L710) by not sending the output but sending the headers.

But fastify seems to incorrectly mark this as an error [here](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/0d6055d3e07b726c9bfbc779550adf78dab967f3/lib/wrapThenable.js#L33)

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
const path = require('path')
const app = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

app.head('/', async (request, reply) => {
  request.log.debug('head')
  try {
    const indexStr = await fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), { encoding: 'utf-8' })
    reply.type('text/html')
    return indexStr
  } catch (e) {
    request.log.error(e)
    return e
  }
})

app.listen(3000)

// curl --location --head 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

When an error is thrown and caught the promise is fulfilled with `undefined` that is causing the error you linked in the source code.

Moreover, when you use `async` functions as handlers, you should return what you want to send in the body or use `return reply.send(content)`

Anyway, consider to don't use `HEAD` methot because [the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) says:

> A response to a HEAD method should not have a body. If so, it must be ignored. Even so, entity headers describing the content of the body, like Content-Length may be included in the response. They don't relate to the body of the HEAD response, which should be empty, but to the body which a similar request using the GET method would have returned as a response.

So your body will be empty:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> content-type: text/html
>
> content-length: 41
>
> Date: Wed, ---
>
> Connection: keep-alive

Comment: This works fine for `index.html` or some string that I return but when I pass back `return reply.sendFile()` it gives me the `undefined` error. When I do `reply.sendFile(uriPath);        return reply.send('');` it replies with a content length of 0 and no etags

Comment: `sendFile` API from `fastify-static` doesn't return anything, so this could be an issue with the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The key is to return the binary stream for files`return fs.readFile(uriPath);` and the string for string responses `return indexPayload;`

```js
import path from 'path';
import fastify from 'fastify';
import staticServe from 'fastify-static';

import { promises as fs } from 'fs';


(async () => {
  const app = fastify({
    logger: !!LOG_LEVEL,
  });

  const filePath = `${ROOT_PATH}*`;
  const serveRoot = path.resolve(SERVE_PATH);


  app.register(staticServe, {
    root: serveRoot,
    serve: false,
  });

  // @ts-ignore
  const getHandler = async (request, reply) => {
    try {
      const { '*': uriPath } = request.params;

      const isFile = !!uriPath.match(/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}(\?.*)?/);
      if (isFile) {
        setCacheControl(reply, FILE_CACHE_CONTROL_MAX_AGE);
        reply.sendFile(uriPath);
        return fs.readFile(uriPath);
      } else {
        const indexPath = 'index.html';
        const indexStr = await fs.readFile(path.join(serveRoot, indexPath), {
          encoding: 'utf-8',
        });
        const indexPayload = await injectEnv(indexStr);
        setCacheControl(reply, INDEX_CACHE_CONTROL_MAX_AGE);
        reply.type('text/html');
        return indexPayload;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      request.log.error(e);
      return e;
    }
  };

  app.get(filePath, { logLevel: LOG_LEVEL }, getHandler);

  // More info here on how it works
  // https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/2061
  app.head(filePath, { logLevel: LOG_LEVEL }, getHandler);

  app.listen(Number.parseInt(PORT, 10), '0.0.0.0', (err: Error) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
})();
```